# Rails 3 sort by nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a category model which has_many events. In the categories controller, I have:

```
@categories = Category.includes(:events).order("events.updated_at DESC")
```

And on my view, I have:

```
@categories.each do |category|
   category.events.each do |event|
```

This results in:

```
Category1 - Event4 - updated 1 minute ago
Category1 - Event2 - updated 1 hour ago
Category1 - Event1 - updated 1 day ago
Category2 - Event3 - updated 3 minutes ago
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
Category1 - Event4 - updated 1 minute ago
Category2 - Event3 - updated 3 minutes ago
Category1 - Event2 - updated 1 hour ago
Category1 - Event1 - updated 1 day ago
```

I've tried adding event.sort_by(&:updated_at) to the view (under events.each do), but I get undefined method.

Does anyone have any ideas on this one?

Comment: Seems to be you getting `@categories` in right order, but then, when you do `category.events.each` it sends queries to database and fetch data from there, not from `@categories`

check rails console output for this